# How to color pictured bars in Highstock chart

Tags: highcharts

How can I color these bars in a Highstock chart above the xaxis label and within the navigator?

[image: highstock bars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tickColor` for a chart and `gridLineColor` for a navigator.

```
    xAxis: {
        tickColor: 'red'
    },
    navigator: {
        xAxis: {
            gridLineColor: 'red'
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w71zvfna/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.tickColor

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.xAxis.gridLineColor